# Почему не работает document.getelementsbyclassname

Tags: html, javascript

```
var getParams = parseGetParams();

 if (getParams['smartname']!=undefined && getParams['smartname'].length > 0 && getParams['smartname']!='undefined'){
    console.log(getParams['smartname']);
  document.getElementsByClassName('smartname').innerHTML=(decodeURI(getParams['smartname'])+ ', ');

};
 function parseGetParams() { 
    var $_GET = {}; 
    var __GET = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&"); 
    for(var i=0; i<__GET.length; i++) { 
    var getVar = __GET[i].split("="); 
    $_GET[getVar[0]] = typeof(getVar[1])=="undefined" ? "" : getVar[1]; 
    } 
    return $_GET; 
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('smartname')[0].innerHTML
```